# Прога ни фурычит(

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Моя программа работает не совсем так, как я бы хотел. По идее, она должна загадывать число, и давать пользователю две попытки угадать его. Вот пример кода:

```
def choose(answer, x):
    if x == answer:
        print('Молодец! Ты выиграл!')
    if x < answer:
        print('Слишком мало!')
    if x > answer:
        print('Слишком много!')
while True:
    x = randint(1, 50)
    try:
        answer = int(input('Я загадал число от одного до пятидесяти. Попробуй отгадать его: '))
        choose()
        try:
            answer = int(input('Следующая попытка: '))
            choose()
        except:
            print('Ошибка, проверьте правильность введённых значений.')
            i = input("Нажмите энтер для продолжения.")
    except:
        print('Ошибка, проверьте правильность введённых значений.')
        i = input("Нажмите энтер для продолжения.")
    Continue = input('Продолжить? (да/нет)')
    if Continue == 'да':
        continue
    elif Continue == 'нет':
        print('Спасибо за игру!')
        break
```

Comment: А кто будет в `choose` передавать `x` и `answer`?

Answer (score 1):

Отметил исправления, подумай почему именно так.

```
import random # <-----
def choose(answer, x):
    if x == answer:
        print('Молодец! Ты выиграл!')
    elif x > answer: # <-----
        print('Слишком мало!')
    elif x < answer: # <-----
        print('Слишком много!')

while True:
    x = random.randint(1, 50) # <-----
    try:
        answer = int(input('Я загадал число от одного до пятидесяти. Попробуй отгадать его: '))
        choose(answer, x)# <-----
        try:
            answer = int(input('Следующая попытка: '))
            choose(answer, x)# <-----
        except:
            print('Ошибка, проверьте правильность введённых значений.')
            i = input("Нажмите энтер для продолжения.")
    except:
        print('Ошибка, проверьте правильность введённых значений.')
        i = input("Нажмите энтер для продолжения.")
    Continue = input('Продолжить? (да/нет)')
    if Continue == 'да':
        continue
    elif Continue == 'нет':
        print('Спасибо за игру!')
        break
    else:# <-----
        print('Ошибка')# <-----
        break# <-----
```